# Let me find canonical questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search, canonical

**Firstly some definition.**

A “***canonical question***” is a question that is the “target” of at least 1 question that has been closed as a duplicate.

“*Direct canonical **weight***” is the number questions that have been closed as a duplicate that points to a given question.

“***Indirect*** canonical weight” is the total of the “canonical weight” and “indirect canonical weight” of questions that have been closed as a duplicate that points at a given question.

**Request**

I wish to be able to find questions for a set of tags (or keywords) sorted by “direct canonical weight” and/or “indirect canonical weight”.

I wish the top “indirect canonical weight” questions to be listed on a tags “home page” along with the wiki.

**Benefit**

- It is likely that these are good questions to learn about the tab from, before asking my own.
- We need great answers to these questions, so let’s make it easy for the experts to find them.
- It will be provide a useful check list, if I think a question is a duplicate but I don’t know of what.

(Or maybe just allow sorting by the number of internal links to a question including the links that are auto inserted when questions are closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: My stack overflowed trying to parse the indirect canonical weight definition.

Comment: @Ben, These days no loops are allowed in the “closed as duplicate” graph, a stack can be used to record visited questions to avoid StackOverflow from old questions that do have loops in the graph.

Comment: @IanRingrose: The definition is recursive - ICW=CW+ICW, so then the question becomes what is CW and ICW which leads back to the definition: ICW=CW+ICW ... stack overflow

Comment: Looks good. With `(1)` the canonical question, `(2)` one of its duplicates, and `(3)` one the the duplicates of `(2)` : `ICW(1) = CW(2) + ICW(2)`, which means `ICW(1) = CW(2) + CW(3) + ICW(3)`.

Comment: Yes! Gief! Great suggestion. I can think of many practical uses for this feature.

Comment: You should be able to write a data.SE query to do this search.  I'm not sure if this would be used widely enough to warrant an actual modification of the site's IDE for it.

Comment: @Servy,   It may get used widely if it is added as a new tab called “Canonical Questions” alongside “newest”, etc

Comment: There's already the "frequent" tab to serve this purpose, and it doesn't get all that much use as is.  This is only a very slight tweak on that tab.

Comment: @Servy, 27 people have up-voted this question for a reason, maybe no  one knows about the "frequent" tab, or it may just be badly name, or maybe something else is needed.

Comment: @IanRingrose Just because 27 people upvoted this question doesn't mean they'd use such a tab if it were added.  If there is already a tab that serves this purpose and people just don't know about it then why would adding yet another tab with a virtually identical purpose help at all?  It would be most likely be equally unused.

Comment: `A “Canonical Question” is a question that is the “target” of at least 1 question that has been closed as a duplicate.` -- That's not what a canonical question is (or at least not how we use the term here), although I suppose you're free to re-invent it as you see fit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, OK replace 1 with say 10

Comment: @IanRingrose: Replace 1 with 2+, make it an "answer your own question" question/answer pair, provide a question and answer that's detailed enough to answer specific questions, but general enough to encompass various scenarios, apply a collaborative lock, etc.  See the PHP and Android Tag Wikis for good examples, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) for the mother of all canonicals.

Comment: Or... we could just create a better FAQ system, instead of the "frequent" crap which is currently in place.

Comment: I didn't know about the frequent tab, and now that I do, I still can't find it.  Whatever it's supposed to be doing, it isn't...

Comment: @Gus It's a tab on the page for a specific tag.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but beware that it'll heavily reward old (and possibly not great, or outright obsolete) canonicals, and downweight new good ones. (So for Python 2-3, it'll definitely make things worse, and just keep recommending the same Q&A that were popular back in 2009 on 2.5/2.6). Not even applying negative-exponential 'ageing' coefficients (ages of both the question, the answer, and the age of accepted answer) would fix that. But yes I agree we could try to improve the 'Frequent' tab. Perhaps for motivation, you could crunch some examples and show us some sample results.

Answer (score 7):

I don't oppose to this feature, but it has a strong bias. On the one hand, a question that has very clear keywords (no obscure language specific term), may only be asked once and be easily found by a search. For example: "how do I do a progress bar in Haskell?". There is only one name for it, you know it; if it exists, you can find it. This question can be regarded as "canonical", and perhaps part of a basic corpus knowledge of Haskell.

On the other hand, there are a lot of beginners questions that are duplicates just because the asker didn't bother to search for it first. The answer, albeit informative, may not be such a good one; perhaps because there is not much to say.

Your proposal is good for problems that I would call "the many names of God". Numpy beginners are usually bitten by views, they do `a = b` expecting a copy of `b` to `a`, jut to see that when they modify `b`, `a` gets mysteriously changed too because they just created a reference. Here there are no obvious keywords, and a search may be unfruitful unless one is seasoned in other languages. By making this accessible, we could provide an entry point for the users that know their problem is basic, they are sure it has been asked before, but don't know how to look for it.