# Making canonical answers easier to find

Tags: discussion, review-queues, canonical

How can we make canonical answers easier to find, especially from the review queue?

I was stumbling upon many Java questions with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, being sure there must be some question that could be canonical. However, I was finding only poor questions of see-my-dump-and-fix-my-error type. Finally I've found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it).

Is there anything I can do to make the canonical question easier to find for future reviewers? An ideal would be for a question to appear first after typing the name of exception in the close-as-duplicate dialog.

I'm not aware of any tag for canonical questions, especially the one that would make the having higher priority in review queues...

Comment: I agree. It's a good idea to make few very-asked question as "more visible". It will be also faster to have a clean Q&A because we will faster find the better answer. Finally, this issue appear in so much lang/question, specially JS or html...

Comment: We really should have some good way to handle these provided by the site. Right now, the solution is just crowdsourced knowledge and initiative. Some tags like JS have listed *some* canonicals in the tag description. But it cannot really fit everything.

Comment: Some related posts that are worth looking at [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254064) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257985).

Comment: Check out the excellent stack app [Duplicate Target Manager](https://stackapps.com/questions/8061/duplicate-target-manager).

Comment: I'm not an SME for either of these areas, and I have no idea how well they're cultivated, but there are [[tag:c++-faq]] and [[tag:r-faq]] FAQ tags, which exist to band together FAQs for those two areas respectively. Maybe those would be useful in others areas likewise?

Comment: I know there was some SEDE query that showed which posts have had the most other posts closed as duplicates of them, it would probably be possible to filter that by tag, and searching that might help.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Here's [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1430008/100-most-duplicated-posts-on-site) that does that (pulls most popular dupes for a given site).

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks for that query. Those numbers are quite mind boggling.

Comment: How does a "canonical question" look after, say, 9-10 years or more? I've seen plenty of "duplicates" point to a question that old, but the answers on the "dup" are more relevant than those on the "original" due to changes in language, software, or 1000 other things because it's only 1-2 years old or maybe only a few months old. We need to be careful when we look at "dups", because relevance to current situations can make even similarly worded questions very much not duplicates of answers using deprecated methods or procedures.

Comment: @computercarguy canonical doesn't mean it's unchanging. It just means that if people have questions *or answers* about X they should go in the canonical. That's in order to start relevant and complete. That's what a canonical is.

Comment: The most proactive way of finding a needle is to avoid dumping a haystack on top of it in the first place, but SO has no reward for using a magnet, and anyone who badmouths the hay gets shouted down. Some communities have resources like lists or wikis for popular duplicate targets, and that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: @VLAZ, you might want to take another look at the definition of [canonical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/what-does-canonical-mean). When a language/library/etc. deprecates features, the "canonical" answer on even a 2 year old question loses it's relevance, really meaning it loses it's "canonical" status. So why would we continue adding answers to an old question that's already answered and lose the currently correct answer among all the outdated answers? I'm not reading 100+ answers to find the one that *might* work when I see dozens that won't on the same question.

Comment: @computercarguy I hate to sound pedantic, but the ELU definition of normal usage of the word canonical does not apply here. If you take a look at the tag wiki of the [meta-tag:canonical], the following meaning is used: *"Canonical questions are those that have the many arms of duplicates pointing back to it as the one truest presentation (or near enough) of the problem. In other words, the most cited when duplicate questions are found."* which precisely matches VLAZ's definition above.

Comment: @OlegValter, but that still doesn't mean those have the most relevant answers. And how does one calculate a "canonical" question when duplicates are used as an "original" to point dups to? Or when a question is marked as a dup of a newer one? Or when a highly upvoted question gets marked as a dup of a lower voted one? I'm sure I've even been to questions that we "dups" but had more visits than the "original", but just haven't paid attention to that statistic. So now "canonical" is another subjective metric that doesn't mean a whole lot.

Comment: @computercarguy may I inquire into how you define "relevance"? Outdatedness is currently being addressed by the "outdated answers" project. Also, there is no rule on dupe-targeting against a *higher* voted question. There is also no rule on dupe-targeting against an *older* question. Canonicals are usually decided on by subject matter experts and often in a form of Meta posts ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312052/11407695) for example - and as you can see, not always does it end up in a creation of a canonical) so yes, canonicals are, inherently, subjective. Just like voting is. [1/2]

Comment: @computercarguy the goal of SO is to have the answers to common questions in one place. In a perfect world, only one question would be asked for each topic. The world is far from perfect and many people misuse SO by asking many times about the same things. That's where duplicates come in and make all those repeat questions point to one. In a perfect world that would be enough and would be done often. But *because* many people misuse SO and ask repeat questions, finding a correct target to link to is often hard. Then other people misuse SO by answering the repeat questions and thus devaluing

Comment: @computercarguy the knowledge by scattering it around. At some point you end up with two or more questions *on the same topic* with different answers. Which breaks the entire model of SO. But nobody at SE seems to be interested in fixing this. And there are people like you further driving a wedge at the core principle of SO by protesting that duplicates should exist. It's a no-win situation. The people who are interested in bringing any sort of order to the chaos of repeat questions are maligned for their effort and people who heap more chaos are rewarded.

Comment: [2/2]. You can also take a look at the discussion under "[Are canonical duplicates useful anymore?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406363/11407695)" for more information on a more in-depth discussion on canonicals.

Comment: @computercarguy Also regarding "*When a language/library/etc. deprecates features, the "canonical" answer on even a 2 year old question loses it's relevance,*" you have to realise that not everybody is using the latest and greatest tech. If somebody wants to do frumpigation in Rapungel then we should have both how frumpingation was done in version 1.2.3 and how it's done in 42.44.45 - people who are stuck with old version can then still benefit from the old solution. People who are interested in updating their approach or just implementing it in the latest version can use the new techniques.

Comment: @VLAZ, but the thing is that there's quite a bit of reason to keep duplicate questions, especially since we can't agree as to what a dup is. See my [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411546/1836461). Are you saying we should strip answers from duplicate questions and put them on the "original"? That would destroy many answers, since they are tailored to the question they answered. And deleting dupes would remove necessary answers.

Comment: @VLAZ, and your last comment is exactly my point about duplicates, where the same question can have different answers because of the language version number and it would be very much useless to lump them all into the same question, since you'd never be able to keep track of what version the answer is using without tagging them like questions, yet we don't have a way to tag answers without editing them, and then that's not as searchable. How about we just fix the Search feature of SO/SE before we try to do anything with something so subjective as "canonical" questions and answers?

Comment: @computercarguy "*Are you saying we should strip answers from duplicate questions and put them on the "original"?*" you can clearly see I've not indicated anything like this at all. "*That would destroy many answers, since they are tailored to the question they answered.*" and this is a reason why. "*And deleting dupes would remove necessary answers.*" this is also something I never indicated should happen. I'd appreciate if you didn't insinuate I've said things that I have not.

Comment: @computercarguy "*the same question can have different answers because of the language version number*" that's actually rarely the case, though. In most cases, *old solutions still work*. We design most programming products to be backwards compatible. So the frumpingation from Rapungel 1.2.3 should still work in 42.44.45. But newer versions introduced alternatives to frumpingate. In fact, an old solution might be what you're looking for even in a new version because of some characteristics that the newer solutions don't do well in.

Comment: @computercarguy "*How about we just fix the Search feature of SO/SE*" yes, I'm all for it! It would make searching for duplicates *much* easier.

Comment: @VLAZ, so what is your suggestion? How do we fix the "problem" if dupes vs "canonical" questions without rearranging and deleting things? And no, changing the major version of a language means there are breaking changes in the language, by modern definition, so an old version of a method or setting may very much not be the correct way anymore. I've seen plenty of changes between sequential changes in a library that are removed, rather than deprecated, so version number matters quite a bit.

Comment: @computercarguy "*How do we fix the "problem"*" [with a magic wand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368077). It requires actual involvement from SE. We need better visibility of duplicate targets. We need people *involved* in finding duplicates instead of continually re-answering them. We need a duplicate closure that doesn't suck to people involved in it. We need better tools to curate content. We need more people curating content. We also need a proper user onboarding, not to be seen as "place to dump code".

Comment: @VLAZ, much of what your answer says is true, but it also makes some untrue assumptions. But what you seem to expect is that nearly SE user is also effectively a librarian of SE. That's just not a reasonable expectation. And being able to classify things really is only effective after searching is effective, which you agree searching needs work. So why not put more pressure on SE for fixing the search functionality instead of complaining about the users not being able to use a broken system? Dupes and most other problems are only symptoms, searching is a major root cause.

Comment: @computercarguy "*But what you seem to expect is that nearly SE user is also effectively a librarian of SE*" no, certainly not "nearly every" I'd love it if more people did it, though. We have enough answers."*why not put more pressure on SE for fixing the search functionality*" sorry, what do you expect me to do which 1. I haven't 2. would be effective? I've supported any suggestion of a better search I've seen. SE have repeatedly shown they don't care about this through their inaction. I'm unaware of what I specifically can do to change this.

Comment: @computercarguy this comment also has an untrue assumption in that question askers are diligent researchers that do check if the question has been asked before or not. Hate to break it, but they are not in the majority of cases, far from it. Bad on-site search is not the root cause of the problem - Google search does an incredible job at getting one relevant results from SO if one puts an even tiny bit of effort in searching most of the time. And here's the problem - the more unconnected and fragmented Q&As we have, the harder it is to give relevant search results.

Comment: Wouldn't some of these strongly held opinions be better suited as an answer?

Comment: on an important note, we are getting quite distracted from the original point of the question - and that is how and whether to make canonical Q&As more visible...

Comment: @OlegValter, wouldn't the Search functionality in SE be a better place to do searching than a 3rd party? How many other apps or sites do you use where you expect to switch to another system to do major functionality for that app/site? VLaz's linked "magic wand" answer complains about how bad it is to search for someone even with his experience with this site. And I said it was *a* root cause, not the only one. Getting users to do more research means making the research easier to do.

Comment: @OlegValter, but how do we make the decision of a canonical Q&A if on-site searching is so bad and how do we make them more visible with on-site searching so bad?

Comment: @computercarguy how many systems do you use which are enormous repositories of posts? :) SE can make the site search be powered by Google's search engine, btw, and everyone would probably be the better for it. In any case, no one is saying that it wouldn't be better to have a first-party search that works well - it is just a sad fact that it isn't, and it is likely infeasible for SE to spend resources to improve it when third-party tools do the job just fine. My point is that the lackluster on-site search is not the reason why people ask duplicate questions [1/2]

Comment: [2/2]. it is their laziness and/or lack of knowledge (i.e. not knowing the correct term). The former we battle with closure itself, the latter - again, with duplicate closure and by *not* deleting good duplicates that offer a different *perspective* that others might search for later. Closer to the point of canonicals, I already mentioned that there is a free-form process of canonicals being suggested for adoption by SMEs and discussed on Meta. Sometimes they form "naturally" and are then curated by the same SMEs. We just do not need 10K questions on "how to loop over an array in JavaScript".

Comment: @OlegValter, we should also make sure people don't DV simply because an answer doesn't use their favorite form of loop in JS. I can't find it, but that's happened to me (I didn't use the `map` function). Also, many good answers are found under questions that aren't popular and don't get votes because people don't see them because the question isn't popular. Replacing the on-site Search with Google would go a long ways to helping avoid dups. It's not a 100% fix, but it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @computercarguy eh, you can't do that (a bit pedantically - `map` is not a loop :)), it's just impossible (Tim's keys theory). Re: unseen questions - that's precisely the problem behind information fragmentation - if they are not connected, they are not seen as often as they could be.

Answer (score 16):

We should direct duplicates to a post addressing the *cause* of a bug, not the *symptoms*.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a symptom that appears because the index used got the wrong value. But the reason *why* it got the wrong value could differ a lot for case to case. Same goes with other generic "there was a bug somewhere" messages such as NullReferenceException or segmentation fault.

One root cause could be that the OP doesn't realize that arrays are 0-indexed. If so, then the link you found is indeed an appropriate canonical duplicate. Not for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` questions but for "OP doesn't grasp 0-indexing" questions. If their index got corrupted for some other reason, lets say race conditions, that dupe target is plain unhelpful.

Requests for "super broad canonical dupe target" pop up from time to time. See for example [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406321/584518). As I wrote there:

> This all seems like lazy moderating to me. NullReferenceException could be anything, it's just in the title because the person who asked the question doesn't know how to ask a good question. The actual problem isn't the exception (or the seg fault etc) - it's just a symptom. The actual problem is the bug somewhere in their code.
>
> The correct way of moderating that isn't to clobber the post with some super-broad FAQ listing all manner of different, unrelated possible causes. Just because you are sick of seing "NullReferenceException plz halp" titles.

We need to drop this lazy moderation culture. Either moderate properly or stay your hand.

---

As for how to make it easier to find canonical dupes, that's a very old problem with SO that has never been solved by the site itself. Users of various tags could solve it by sharing their collection of canonical dupe links with others.

Now what I would do if looking for a dupe, is to go check the tag wiki, [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) in this case. And look, there is some manner of FAQ link collection there! Scrolling through that list, I find the very canonical dupe you refer to below "debugging". (Not very intuitive perhaps, I'd expect to find it below arrays/containers or exceptions, but anyway... it is there.)

Other languages have made such FAQ link collections in their tag wiki too, which I believe is the best solution, long as veteran users of that tag maintain it and know where to find it. The only language tag I know of that actually used a special tag for canonical dupes is [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), which is admittedly a "meta tag" - using a tag wasn't the best idea to begin with. We can only use 5 tags per post and in this case 2 are already gone for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) by default.

Comment: *"We need to drop this lazy moderation culture. Either moderate properly or stay your hand"* - indeed. Essentially what is true for reviewing is also true for moderating. The fact that there is far too much junk flowing in and the company not doing anything about it does not change the fact that you should still try to do the right thing.

Comment: People don't search for "why can't I reference an array index that is greater than the length of the array in Java?". They search for (if they search at all) `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` plus *maybe* `java`. and that's it. *That's* why having a catch-all "super broad canonical dupe target" is nice to have; for people to land on when searching. Now, it might be better if the *answers* to that catch-all question were spread amongst more targeted dupes for symptoms, like [What does this symbol mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/215552), but a single target for searchers seems good.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not understanding that very generic error messages are unhelpful is obviously part of the problem, see the other post that I linked. Obviously if people knew the cause of the problem, they wouldn't need to ask, but ending up with some generic post isn't necessarily helpful. This is a Q&A site and not wikipedia - our goal isn't to build wikipedia 2 or to collectively write a Java book. First of all I could obviously just RTFM about what `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means. But if that turns out unhelpful, that's when I would ask on SO.

Comment: Pretty much **the only possibly way** someone can or would look for "the cause" of an issue where the symptom is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is by typing that error into Google. To say that a (well-written) canonical post explaining what that error means and how to generally investigate it is not a catch-all duplicate is, in my honest and rather blunt opinion, a fundamental misunderstanding of what this site attempts to do and what duplicates are for (letting people find answers through Google is a big part of that). If you want to help with OP's specific problem, fair enough, ... 1/2

Comment: ... but that doesn't mean the question should stay open (those are not one and the same). Although I am open to a counter-argument explaining what value it would bring to keep a bunch of questions open that all have different answers but ask the same thing ("why do I get this error", with different code, but you can't realistically search for code), or how you envision users searching for and finding the cause of the problem in this case, if not by simply Googling the error (which I know is the first thing I usually try when I run into a new error). 2/2

Comment: I would perhaps go even further and argue most "my code doesn't work" questions have little to no future value and are thus simply not a good fit for [so]. I'm not fundamentally opposed to those questions, I just don't think they belong here. But having a canonical post which points people in the right general direction and gives them some idea of how to go about fixing their issue (even though such a post might need to present a few possibilities and can't tell them where exactly they're going wrong in their code) is greatly preferred above simply shutting down all such questions. 3?/2

Comment: @BernhardBarker If they had taken beginner classes they would know how to use a debugger. And then the place to look to find the cause is your own code base, not the Internet. Once they've at least tried to debug it, they are in a much better position to ask a good question. _You don't learn programming by random google searches, you learn it by reading books/tutorials, taking classes and of course by coding._ Lazy coddled kids who want to know the answer to everything instantly, without any effort on their part, have no place in any professional setting, including programming.

Comment: And again, SO is still not wikipedia, nor is it RTFM. If failing to search in those two places, well then SO might be the next stop. Again, some effort is required by the person looking for a solution to solve the issue themselves.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not entirely sure how to connect your comment and your answer. 99.9% of questions I've seen about index-out-of-bounds and null-reference exceptions involve a basic lack of understanding of what those exceptions mean and/or a lack of debugging (and/or not knowing that arrays are 0-indexed for the former), and your comment seems to suggest that we shouldn't "address the cause" of those (as per your answer), but rather that they don't belong on SO at all, i.e. close them (but of course the remaining 0.1% may belong here in some form). 1/3

Comment: As for whether we should have a canonical basically explaining, to fix some error, that someone should debug and possibly how to do so, perhaps that's a separate discussion altogether (closing something as a debug question or as a duplicate seems similar enough to me). But to me that's not so much an issue of whether the non-canonical version of the "how do I fix this error" question strictly belongs on SO (although perhaps you could argue it sets a bad precedent). It's a question of whether is the Q in Q&A (it is indeed a question that people ask), ... 2/3

Comment: ... whether it's broadly on topic (it is indeed about programming), whether it's as specific as it can or should reasonably be (yes, you can't really get much more specific than "how do I fix this error" to address the 99.9% of cases), whether a useful answer can reasonably fit within an answer post (I'd argue it can), whether it's to the benefit of the internet at large (it probably is) and whether people come here for an answer to it (they do; it would probably be best if they solve their question in different ways, but they do still come here often). 3/3

Comment: I second @BernhardBarker, Lundin - the tone of your answer appears to entirely conflict with your comments below said answer. You complain about "lazy moderation culture" in the answer, but your comment complains about "lazy coddled kids".

Comment: @BernhardBarker Basically, the root cause of the exception may be that the OP doesn't grasp that arrays are 0-indexed. But the root cause of why they are having that question is that they didn't study the language they are coding in. "Super broad FAQ posts" are used when people really mean to say "you obviously didn't study the basics, go read the chapter about arrays in your Java book". So far I can relate completely to the urge to just clobber these kind of crap questions with a duplicate closure. ->

Comment: But instead of sugar-coating it like that, we should be able to just close posts because of non-existent research, such as attempting to use arrays without even studying them. Because closing as duplicate turns problematic when the post is actually not a duplicate of the target. Suppose lots of people get the exception because of race conditions, as the example I gave. Then gets closed as dupe to the super broad FAQ and suddenly we have started to incorrectly teach the site that race conditions are caused by not starting array access with index 0. ->

Comment: And then when you google your race condition bugs like you want to do, you end up in some random unrelated post about arrays. This is the reason why lazy moderation is bad.

Comment: @Lundin I'd argue/suspect that canonical posts covering (at least) the basics helps a great many people (you could argue that they should read a book or something instead, and they probably should, but we can't force people to learn the way we think they should, or maybe they're just not that far in the book yet, they missed that information or it's a bad book). It's obviously bad to close questions as duplicates of other questions where that question's answer doesn't address their issue. But, instead of dissuading people from closing things as duplicates of some canonical post covering ...

Comment: ... the basics, the logical solution there for me would be to add more complex causes to the canonical post (or link to other posts that do so from there, if adding it directly would take too much space). If something looks like a duplicate of a canonical post but isn't one, it should be edited to clearly differentiate it. If that isn't possible (perhaps because you can't really get more specific than "why am I getting this error?" without beginning to answer the question), it's not a problem with closing it as a duplicate, it's a problem with the canonical post not covering that use case.

Comment: @BernhardBarker "To say that a (well-written) canonical post explaining what that error means and how to generally investigate ..." To me this feels like not a Q&A (because it's not focused enough), but rather like some kind of meta Q&A (not this meta here, rather programming problems meta). Maybe we could invent some new form of content that allows such general helpful content to be created, say articles or meta Q&A. Q&A should be reserved for specific problems, I think, but other forms of content could basically direct people to these specific problems.

Comment: @Trilarion Perhaps. Canonical Q&A's is just doing the best we can with what's available. I'd say some work fairly well, although they may send some mixed messages about what's appropriate here (but some sort of note about it being a canonical post in the question or a comment would probably help with that). Putting them elsewhere might also work, although at that point it almost makes more sense to just create an entirely unrelated site for that with more suitable (reputation + ask/answer) functionality. Although having it under SO has the advantage of it already existing ... and having users.

Comment: @BernhardBarker The content of SO is free and could move anywhere really fast. The expert users and the brand/domain name are the real sticky part so far.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not convinced there would be a big desire to have a separate place or separate functionality for canonical Q&A's on SO (possibly for almost the same reason Articles failed). Most would probably argue that this need is already served by the main Q&A, and it is to a large extent (which also makes it hard to launch a successful competing product). But there are perhaps enough experts who are frustrated with the endless supply of low-quality questions to be drawn in by something that's purpose-built to attempt to address that.

Comment: So, the "lazy moderation" is less about marking the question as a dupe than it is adding an answer to the dupe target explaining the edge case that's missing? Because it seems to me, if you think that case is missing from the dupe target for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, *you should add it* rather than complaining about other people being lazy. More and more I see people whining about other people's laziness with no willingness to do any work themselves. Wrong dupe? Complain about it, but don't find the right one! See a rude comment? Complain about it, but don't take the time to flag it!

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, that is not a good solution because we already have a big problem with low quality canonical dupes. That is, some up-voted thing where someone posted a decent but narrow answer about A. Then someone else posted an answer about B. Then someone realizes that in order to fully answer the question, we need A+B+C. So they post an answer about B+C, because A was already so good. Then over the years some 5+ people stop by "oh look, high traffic post, I'll post too" and posting a duplicate of any combination of A+B+C. Almost every canonical dupe on SO looks like this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Coincidently I just wrote [a post](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/284169/284257#answer-284257) about this problem over at Codiact, where I encouraged not to repeat SO's mistake by implementing a similarly flawed close-as-duplicate system as we got here.

Comment: To make a real example. _The_ most FAQ below the C tag on SO is "why doesn't my crappy i = i++; code compile". This is by far the most common C question and the by far most frequently used canonical dupe is [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior). It has been up-votes to the skies. The canonical question itself is good too.

Comment: However, in order to actually answer the question completely (it's a somewhat complex matter), an answer needs to address the following: sequence points, side affects, undefined behavior. Ideally by quoting canonical sources, in this case the ISO C standard.

Comment: The accepted and most up-voted answer (score 590) only says "it's undefined behavior". It's incomplete and rather bad, because it neither explains anything or lists any sources other than a link to wikipedia. Next answer says "just compile and see what happens" which is even worse, this is a really bad answer since it doesn't explain anything and doesn't mention any of the bugs and dangers. Next answer makes the relevant quote about sequence points. It does not explain them. It does not explain undefined behavior. It does not mention side affects - it's a very incomplete answer.

Comment: Next answer ("only" score 76) by haccks is the first good answer we encounter. It's complete, addressing all the mentioned issues. This answer should be the canonical, not all the other 10+ bad noise answers in that post.

Comment: (Typo but too late to edit comment... Rather, it should have said, the most FAQ is "why does my crappy i = i++; code give result x rather than y". It compiles of course.)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I largely agree with (trying to) fix the canonical instead of objecting to closure. Although simply adding an answer may not be all that effective, as there may already be many redundant answers, so it would be easy to miss this one. The ideal canonical would probably only have 1 answer, which you'd then be able to edit instead (and it should probably be Community Wiki, to avoid or minimise the issue of post ownership). If the canonical isn't ideal, making it so, or making a better one (with community support), may be unrealistic. But not closing things is not good either.

Answer (score 3):

The advanced search tools *do* work in the duplicate search box. In this case since you're looking for a canonical that has a few hundred votes, you can use `score:100` and adjust the minimum score until you find your target.

Unfortunately... this isn't something you can do to make the canonical easier to find for *others*. The most you can do is edit the canonical and other questions that appeared above it... but that's somewhat moot when there's thousands and more being posted daily.

We could certainly spitball on changes to the dupe search to make the results that are returned more likely to be relevant, such as using score to filter the results when there are more than 150 results, or prioritizing existing dupe targets, but these have similar downsides... we have to decide what downsides are worth dealing with to end up with a better solution.

Comment: well, other than keyword-spamming the canonical's question (please don't)

Answer (score 1):

The reality is we need to get SE to give us better tools to use the site better. Without that, we are just complaining to each other about how badly we use the site with no hope of actually making the site, questions, or answers better.

### Searching

One way we can get more people to search for existing questions and answers, instead of asking new questions, is to have SE make their on-site search functionality better. If that means they scrap their current functionality and replace it with Google or some other easy to use and reliable 3rd party system, but make it work on-site, then that works for me.

This includes the real-time searching happening when creating a title for a new question. Rarely have I found those results to be useful, and sometimes they aren't even relevant.

Once we get a better search functionality, we should automatically see fewer duplicate questions being generated. Not everyone, especially new users, will understand how broken the on-site Search bar is, so will use it thinking that it's working. They will then create a new question because that search failed them and so did the search when creating a title for their duplicate question.

Even those of us with lots of experience using SE have a hard time finding the correct solutions, including when looking to mark an question a duplicate. User VLAZ mentioned it in a comment with their [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367906/magic-wand-time-what-does-your-community-need/368077#368077) describing some of their problems.

### Answer tags

Answers should get the same kinds of tags that questions do. We can tag them with language/library/etc. names and version numbers so people looking for answers aren't trying solutions that have been deprecated since the answer was written or is for a later version than the user needs. I can't tell you how many times I've gone though this myself.

I've seen questions that ask for specific languages to be used to solve a problem, then answers use a different language as an example. Tagging the answer with the language can be helpful, since sticking to the same language the question asks for isn't always necessary or followed.

We can also use these tags to make searching more reliable and relevant.

### Other considerations

We should also consider having SE drop the -1 cost to reputation points for down voting. There's long discussions about that, so I won't get into it here.

We need more positive rewards for going through queues, marking items as duplicates, flagging for deletion, and more. Even editing a question or answer should gain you more than 2 points. And really, [positive reinforcement](https://pavlok.com/blog/positive-vs-negative-reinforcement-which-is-more-effective/) works better than [punishment](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymaker-psychology/chapter/operant-conditioning/). I'll even admit that I've refused to downvote because I just gained a privilege and downvoting would have taken it away.

### Bugs and features with tracking

We currently use Meta as a bug reporting and feature request system. Unfortunately, that's not a very good system, which is apparent when there are so many duplicates asking for the same features and bug fixes year after year, yet nothing happens. We need to get SE to adopt a better system, then use it appropriately as users to get the features we need.

In a comment on the original question I asked the question: "why not put more pressure on SE for fixing the search functionality". And user VLAZ replied with:

> sorry, what do you expect me to do which 1. I haven't 2. would be effective? I've supported any suggestion of a better search I've seen. SE have repeatedly shown they don't care about this through their inaction. I'm unaware of what I specifically can do to change this.

Well, we get them to commit to a new system and hold them to it. As of right now, that might be like pulling teeth, but it would go a long way to making things better, instead of complaining into the apparent void and echo chamber of Meta, where SE doesn't really seem to care no matter how many users repeat the same sentiments.

How does getting bug and feature tracking help fix the OP's problem? Well, it doesn't directly, but it does help us get the Search bar fixed, better ways to search (answer tags), and deal with other problems hindering/preventing question-askers from doing the research they should.

### Conclusion

If users don't have the on-site tools they need to research properly, then we can't really complain when they don't do research. If they/we can't find duplicates, we shouldn't complain when people don't find them without prior knowledge of them. Heck, I can't find answers **I've** written because of how badly the Search functionality works.

Incidentally, I see many people complaining about users doing something wrong, or not doing something when it really comes down to the site not working as well as it should. More emphasis should be put on getting SE to fix problems than getting users to work around them.

[Another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411803/11407695) here by [Lundin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) says to mark duplicates by looking at the root cause, rather than the symptoms. Well, I think we should fix the problems on SE at the root cause of the site rather than the symptom of how people use it. This will actually reduce the amount of moderation and curation needed (as well as posting on Meta about how bad users are), reducing the amount of work everyone needs to do, instead of asking everyone to do more work.

Once we get Searching and other systems fixed, canonical answers should start popping up on their own more often without having to be curated by subject matter experts so much.

**Edit:** There's already a `feature-request` out for replacing the built-in search with Google results, but that's 7.5 years old and apparently didn't go anywhere.

[Replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254093/replace-the-built-in-elastic-search-with-results-from-google-instead?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: on a tangential note, answer tagging is [currently under discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406675/11407695) (well, more precisely the discussion is planned to happen as one of the next steps after unpinning accepted answers) as part of the "outdated answers" project (as a way to mark answers as version-specific in a clear manner)

Comment: "is to have SE make their on-site search functionality better" 99% of all traffic comes via google. The most hit route is /question/<id>. Nobody use SE to search, they use google to search. SE is ok with that. **The problem is the people that don't search at all.**

Comment: @Braiam, your comment contradicts itself. You say "99% of all traffic comes from Google", which is a search engine, so people are doing searches, especially when they come in the for of "question/<id>", as you say. I think you mean some people don't search as much as you'd like. BTW, do you have definitive proof that "nobody" uses the SE search? I've used it, only to realize just how bad it is. For that matter, do you have proof that 99% of all hits come from Google? I find that hard to believe. I bet a lot are from HNQ and linked/duplicate questions. That would fit the same URL format.

Comment: @computercarguy 94.8% to be exact, as of this comment.

Comment: @KevinB, do you have a source for that number?

Comment: Yes, the tools users with more than 25k rep gain access to.

Comment: @KevinB, that's at 25k and not going to happen any time soon for most of us, if ever. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges It's also the last privilege to earn.

Comment: Also, to be fair, that 94.8% is all search engines, not just google. But google makes up the overwhelming majority and I don't think other search engines making up a small portion of the result is significant to Braiam's claim. You could certainly be pedantic and say "Hah, clearly people do use SE's search!" but that's missing the point entirely.

Comment: @KevinB, so would "all search engines" include SE's search or only off-site searches?

Comment: only off-site search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237790/discussion-between-computercarguy-and-kevin-b).

Comment: @computercarguy Well, the number of [hits for /search is well below 1%](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/). So, for all intents and purposes internal search engine is not used. Note, if you use authenticated users it would be above 1%, but those people rarely are looking for answers.

Comment: @Braiam, if you are talking about users with an account when you say "authenticated users", then those users look for questions a considerable amount according to a blog from 2017. https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/ But, they probably aren't using the on-site Search because they know it's so bad, which is why I and [others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254093/replace-the-built-in-elastic-search-with-results-from-google-instead) suggest to fix it.

Comment: You are linking the same blog post I linked. You are comparing a datapoint against itself. I said that over 1% of authenticated users use /search, but those are only 15% of all traffic. So, the amount of anonymous users that use search is less than that.